# How to define a current_model for a model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think my question title is bit confusing. But what I am meaning to ask is I am creating my own authentication system using mobile. Just like devise comes with `current_user` to create a session, I want to know how can I achieve same on a different model.

I have a model called **Commuter**. It also has a id with it.
A record of `commuter` looks like this.

`Commuter.last`

`<Commuter id: 867, phone_number: "9483942090">`

I am trying to create a session after verfying the mobile number with my controller method as follows:

```
def verify
    @commuter = Commuter.where(phone_number: params[:phone_number]).first
    if (@commuter && @commuter.authenticate_otp(params[:otp],drift:300))
      @commuter.auth_active = true
      if @commuter.save
        #Removed from session after verified it
        session[:phone_number] = nil
        session[:is_verified] = nil
        #signed in commuter after verified it
        sign_in(:commuter, @commuter)
        flash[:notice] = "Your mobile no is verified."
      end
    else
      flash[:alert] = "You have entered wrong otp.Please check again."
    end
    puts "#{current_commuter.phone_number}"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

I just a `puts` there to debug. So right now I am getting `current_commuter` as undefined local variable for obvious reasons I guess. So I wanted to know how can achieve this session based current commuter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the Commuter id in the session as `session[:cid] = 1` and create a method on your base controller like this

```
def current_commuter
  @commuter ||= Commuter.find session[:cid]
end


helper_method :current_commuter
```

Comment: I did this. Then I added a line in view file `<%if current_commuter.present? %>` then link to a Dashboard. Then I get this error on loading home page. `Couldn't find Commuter without an ID`. If I remove that line I am not getting that error.

Comment: probably you are not saving the commuter id inside the session with `session[:cid]  = @commuter.id` try debug the call